# Can MySQL be used instead of PostGIS database in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector, mysql

I'm having trouble connecting to a MySQL DB in QGIS and am wondering if maybe I'm expecting MySQL to be a replacement for PostGIS when it isn't.

Can I use MySQL to store large vector datasets or must I use PostGIS?

Comment: MySQL's comparable is PostgreSQL, not PostGIS.

Comment: So, where does that put mysql as far as usability for vector data?

Comment: I do not know if QGIS has its own MySQL connector or if it is using the GDAL driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mysql.html. Spatial support in MySQL is a bit limited but people do use it as well as MariaDB. About the capabilities read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought but was having trouble connecting to it. Says the new database isn't a known data type.

Comment: The general answer is it depends, the odds are you most likely will end up using PostrgreSQL with PostGIS. Most people do for many advantages it has over MySQL, including being faster, having better spatial indexing options with big vector datasets, more and better built-in spatial functions etc. You still might be an exception though, e.g. you already have MySQL server for major non-spatial datasets, and just need to store a bit of spatial data with it.